# 101 Error #Too Many SOQL queries

Tags: apex, trigger

**Trigger :**

```
/*
 *  Purpose: This trigger fires when first time Opportunity owner changes from 
    DFCS guest user </br>
 *           to an existing User and records the response time on Opportunity.
 *  @Author: Surinder
 *   Test Class - DFCS_defaultBusinessSegment_test
 *
 *  
 */
trigger DFCS_responseDateCal on Opportunity (before insert,before update)
{
    public static long hours;
    public static Integer value;
    //public static Id ownerId = [select id from user where Name='00541000003mBQJ' LIMIT 1].id; //DFCS guest User profile Id
    public static Id oldOpp;

    //[Pranjal Added] Synchs values of two fields on Opp
     DFCS_updateAccName.updateCustomerLegalName(Trigger.new);


   If(Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) 
    {
         /*
          oldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).OwnerId;
          If((oldOpp==ownerId) && (Opp.ownerID!=ownerId)&& (opp.Response_check__c==False))
          {
              opp.Response_Date__c = system.now();
              opp.Response_check__c=True;
              BusinessHours bh = [select Id from BusinessHours where isdefault = true ];
              hours = Math.abs(BusinessHours.diff(bh.id,opp.createdDate,opp.Response_Date__c)/1000/60/60); 
              value = hours.intValue();
              opp.Response_Time_Bus_Hours__c=value;
         }
      */

      DFCS_defaultBusinessSegment.SLA_Lapse_Days(Trigger.new);   // Test class - DFCS_defaultBusinessSegment_test

    }
    }
}
```

While updating opp, a trigger call this class. I am getting this error while mass updating records by data loader. Not able to find the issue in this code. Please advice what could be the error.

Class-

```
/*
 *  Purpose: Defaults Business segment as per Custom settings data and populates this field.
 *           Products__c = "Support Service Requested"
 *           Calculates SLA Lapse Days on Opportunity
 *           Calculate response Time on Opportunity
 *           
 *  @Author: Pranjal Singh           
 **/
public class DFCS_defaultBusinessSegment
{
  public static Integer i =0;
  //public static Integer RECORD_COUNT = [SELECT count() FROM BusinessSegment__c];
  public static long hours;
  public static Integer value;
  public static ID  BussId  = [select Id from BusinessHours where isdefault = true].ID;


  public static void SLA_Lapse_Days(List<Opportunity> oppList) 
  {
    Date CurDate= system.Today(); 
   // if(bh == null) bh = [select Id from BusinessHours where isdefault = true ];
    for(Opportunity opp: oppList)
     {
        if(opp.Opportunity_SLA_Commitment_Date__c!=Null)
           {

             if((opp.Release_Date__c!=Null)&&(opp.Release_Date__c>opp.Opportunity_SLA_Commitment_Date__c))
              {

              hours = Math.abs(BusinessHours.diff(BussId,opp.Release_Date__c,opp.Opportunity_SLA_Commitment_Date__c)/1000/60/60); 
              value = hours.intValue();
              value= value/9;
              opp.SLA_Lapase_Days__c=value;
              }

              if((opp.Release_Date__c==Null)&&(opp.Opportunity_SLA_Commitment_Date__c<=CurDate))
              {

              hours = Math.abs(BusinessHours.diff(BussId,opp.Opportunity_SLA_Commitment_Date__c,CurDate)/1000/60/60); 
              value = hours.intValue();
              value= value/9;
              opp.SLA_Lapase_Days__c=value;
              }

             if((opp.Release_Date__c!=Null)&&(opp.Release_Date__c<opp.Opportunity_SLA_Commitment_Date__c)||(opp.Release_Date__c==Null)&&(opp.Opportunity_SLA_Commitment_Date__c>=CurDate))
              {
              opp.SLA_Lapase_Days__c=0;
              }

              } 

           }

     }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you just need to do this

```
trigger DFCS_responseDateCal on Opportunity (before insert,before update)
    {
        public static long hours;
        public static Integer value;
        //public static Id ownerId = [select id from user where Name='00541000003mBQJ' LIMIT 1].id; //DFCS guest User profile Id
        public static Id oldOpp;

        //[Pranjal Added] Synchs values of two fields on Opp
         DFCS_updateAccName.updateCustomerLegalName(Trigger.new);


       If(Trigger.isUpdate)
        {
         DFCS_defaultBusinessSegment.SLA_Lapse_Days(Trigger.new);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `this` is undefined, you would want to highlight what changes are required to fix the error; to make your answer better.

Comment: if surender wrote code, he knows what is missing or what is not so I don't think of any reason but thank you I will take care of that.

Comment: That doesn't make the question nor answer valuable to the community. I have voted this question down because it is not useful to anyone outside of *maybe* the OP.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because it's just a code dump with no explanation. Good answers, to me, are ones that explain what the OP's (**O**riginal **P**ost [or Poster of the question]) problem was, and how your code fixes it. Without explanation, people with similar problems that come to this question in the future are unlikely to be able to know how to apply this to their own situation. Further, if your code is wrong, that usually sets off a chain of comments like "it didn't work" and "try this [additional code in comment]", which is similarly unhelpful.

Answer (score 4):

While hasectic saif's answer presents the solution, they haven't shown their work, or explained why it works (or what the issue was).

Taking a look at your provided trigger, we see the following:

```
for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) 
{
    // I've removed the commented out lines here
    DFCS_defaultBusinessSegment.SLA_Lapse_Days(Trigger.new);   // Test class - DFCS_defaultBusinessSegment_test
}
```

That, to me, is a bit of a red flag. You're calling a helper class, passing it `Trigger.new`, and doing that all inside of a loop over `trigger.new`.

Looking at your helper class, I see some queries that are commented out. That's a bit concerning, but shouldn't be causing an issue. I also don't see any DML being performed in your helper method, nor any other methods being called (besides `BusinessHours.diff()`).

The only query that I do see is one that initializes a static class variable for `DFCS_defaultBusinessSegment`. Unless I don't understand static variables as well as I think I do, that query should only be getting run once for the entire transaction (no matter how many times you call a static method of the class).

Based on that, the code you've provided can't possibly be the root cause of your error. It's simply the code that caused you to use the query that put you over the limit.

Regardless of whether or not it's causing your error though, I would suggest cleaning up your trigger. Iterating over `trigger.new` only to pass the same context variable to your helper method and loop over it there as well isn't doing anyone any favors. Instead of looping a max of 200 times per trigger chunk, you're looping (at maximum) 40,000 times.

With that many loop iterations, even the smallest differences in code can lead to noticeable (if not significant) increases in limit usage (particularly CPU time, the more cpu time you use, the more sluggish your code will feel).

```
trigger DFCS_responseDateCal on Opportunity (before insert,before update)
{
    public static long hours;
    public static Integer value;
    //public static Id ownerId = [select id from user where Name='00541000003mBQJ' LIMIT 1].id; //DFCS guest User profile Id
    public static Id oldOpp;

    //[Pranjal Added] Synchs values of two fields on Opp
     DFCS_updateAccName.updateCustomerLegalName(Trigger.new);


    If(Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        // since your helper class loops over trigger.new itself, there's absolutely
        //   no reason to keep it inside of this loop
        /*for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) 
        {
            // removed commented out code
            DFCS_defaultBusinessSegment.SLA_Lapse_Days(Trigger.new);   // Test class - DFCS_defaultBusinessSegment_test

        }*/

        // Outside of a loop is where this code should be
        DFCS_defaultBusinessSegment.SLA_Lapse_Days(Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

If you're still running over the query limit, then it's time to look elsewhere. Capture a debug log or two, and dig through it to see where you're using queries. Figure out what other code is being run when you update your `Opportunity` records, and see if there are any other double loops over `Trigger.new`. If you have built processes with Process Builder, that could also be causing issues (while Salesforce has improved the bulk behavior of PB, it's still very sorely lacking. PB and Triggers don't mix well, the general advice is to stick to one or the other).